# Apache storing cache of js file

Tags: angularjs, git, apache, caching, server

I updated a web applications front end built in angularjs on a remote server hosted on rackspace , the server already has a previous version of the same web app that was uploaded by me one day before this update . The uploading was done by local ( git push ) -> bitbucket -> remote server ( git pull ) . After uploading I reloaded the web page in firefox but it was still loading the previous version , I tried the same in private window of firefox and a new chrome window but it was still loading the previous version . I tried these things :

1) To upload I used ,

```
 git add --all  
 git commit -m "my commit" 
 git push origin master
```

here origin was bitbucket repository url of my web app . Then on server I did

```
git fetch 

git reset --hard origin/master
```

This works well for me every time , and php files get updated just after uploading the files but angularjs or js file's old version was served .

2) I checked if the ManagerService.js file was updated on bitbucket to ensure that git push worked well and there was new version of the file on the bitbucket .

3) I checked the file on the server by using VIM and ManagerService.js file has the new updated code on the server .

4) I loaded the url of the ManagerService.js by giving the absolute url ( eg. www.example.com/js/services/ManagerService.js) of the file in my phone and still the old file was served .
By now I was quite sure that it is happening because of Apache creating cache of my js file so I googled  and ran this command on the terminal of my server 
as mentioned in this url ( http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-clear-cached-memory-on-ubuntu.html )

```
sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

5) I also changed the sequence of the lines I changed in ManagerService.js , and did the upload again .

But still no success .
Finally I git cloned the project in a new directory and it worked well . 
If I face the same issue this time what should I do to get the new updated file .

Comment: `I loaded the url of the ManagerService.js by giving the absolute url of the file in my phone and still the old file was served` ... this sounds like maybe your phone is caching a previous version of a JS file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : I loaded the file with absolute url , example.com/js/services/managerService.js in private / incognito windows of chrome and firefox and still the old file was loaded . Do you think apache can create cache of js files ?

Comment: I think the _browser_ may be what is creating the cache.  Try clearing your browser cache in Chrome and Firefox and see what happens.  By the way, your Git commands looks OK, at least from a cursory glance.

Comment: This seems to be the issue with Your local browser cache, and we ourselves have faced this multiple times. Go ahead with `Ctrl + Shift + Del` and try reloading the page.

Comment: For anyone who faces similar kind of trouble my best guess is that it was just an advanced case of cache . I had web developer tool installed and had cache disabled by that . In my phone I was most probably getting the file that chrome stored from my desktop . If you face similar kind of trouble please try clearing cache manually .

Answer (score 0):

I think rackspace serves your static content through CDN. Check there is anything you can avoid this. I faced same issues with Google App Engine environment. Change file name and deploy your application will solve your problem.